# Posted image is not appearing in Firebase Recycler View

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to retrieve all users posts from firebase database and want to display it on Main Activity with the help Recycler View and Firebase Recycler Adapter. 
But After Successfully Uploading The Image to Firebase database , i can see the uploaded image in storage section of firebase console but in database section it's showing something like -

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@3c50f45

So I think the problem is with this line of code :

`downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();`

**CODE:**

```
private Uri ImageUri;
    private StorageReference PostsImagesRefrence;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef, PostsRef;
    PostsImagesRefrence = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

    StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesRefrence.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");

            filePath.putFile(ImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "image uploaded successfully to Storage...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        SavingPostInformationToDatabase();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            });
```

**Design View And Actual Output Image:**

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNKFu.png)

[View After Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2VQh.jpg)

Please Try To provide me a correct code , help me as i am a newbie and don't know about Android Studio , and want to complete this College Project.

Comment: So what is wrong with this code, only the image is not displayed?

Comment: Does your `postImage` hold the correct value for your image?

Comment: Try to log its value.

Comment: @AlexMamo i guess you can answer it now , i've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved It , I was using old method for storing the image to firebase database.

Following changes has been done to solve it :

```
final StorageReference filePath = PostsImagesRefrence.child("Post Images").child(ImageUri.getLastPathSegment() + postRandomName + ".jpg");

            final UploadTask uploadTask =filePath.putFile(ImageUri);

            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                {
                    String message =e.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
            {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
            {
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully to Storage...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception
                    {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        downloadUrl= filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                        return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Stored Image Successfully to Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SavingPostInformationToDatabase();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
String userFullName = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
String userProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
```

To

```
String userFullName = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue(String.class);
String userProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue(String.class);
```

**EDIT:** Try this

```
dateRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl) 
    {                
       downloadUrlString = downloadUrl.toString();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks For The Answer , but it's Not Working.

Comment: just tell me is this line of code , correct ?                                                                                        `downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();`

Comment: Did you check if your database is populated and the image is uploaded properly?